# Numba in conda environment failing tests

Tags: python, numba, conda

I'm trying to set up a conda environment for developing numba. I cloned the git repo and set up the environment in the suggested way, like:

```
$ conda create -n numba-dev python numpy llvmlite funcsigs # create numba env
$ source activate numba-dev # activate the numba-dev environment
(numba-dev)$ python setup.py install # install numba to the env
(numba-dev)$ ./runtests.p
...


Ran 1947 tests in 39.884s

FAILED (failures=6, errors=1522, skipped=10)
```

Most of errors are like

```
Internal error:
AttributeError: 'Module' object has no attribute 'get_global'
File "numba/targets/randomimpl.py", line 221
```

or

```
AttributeError: Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)
'Module' object has no attribute 'get_global'
```

`get_global` occurs once in `numba/targets/base.py` line 268. But the context of it is not enlightening me.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what is going on in with your issue, but if you just want the latest dev version (basically what's in `master` on Github), there is an automatic build that you can get via `conda install -c numba numba`

Comment: @JoshAdel would like to build numba master with my own changes so this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Happens for me since the upgrade to 0.18.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was asked before the 0.18.x releases and numba master had already switch to the latest llvmlite.  For those interested in building  numba master, there is a [numba channel on binstar](https://binstar.org/numba) that host builds of numba and llvmlite. You can do `conda install -c numba llvmlite` to install/update llvmlite.